# Как организовать взаимодействие бэкенда с фронтендом по инициативе бэкенда

Tags: javascript, html, http, frontend, backend

**ИМЕЕТСЯ**: Бэкенд написан на C/C++ и связан с библиотекой HTTP-сервера/клиента тоже на C/C++. Фронтенд написан на HTML/CSS/JavaScript. Взаимодействие фронтенда с бэкендом происходит через HTTP-запросы и ответы и всегда по инициативе фронтенда. Это определённый набор команд управления, периодический запрос статистики для отрисовки графиков и периодический опрос наподобие keep alive.

**ТРЕБУЕТСЯ**: Возникла необходимость изредка отправлять некоторые данные от бэкенда к фронтенду по инициативе бэкенда. Нет никаких проблем поднять на бэкенде HTTP-клиент и отправлять с него HTTP-запросы, но как фронтенд будет их получать? При этом хочется оставить фронтенд в виде веб-страницы и желательно без установки каких-то дополнительных серверов, а ограничиться только минимальным набором локальных версий свободно распространяемых JavaScript библиотек.

**МОИ ВАРИАНТЫ**:

1. На стороне бэкенда делать очередь отправляемых запросов и отправлять их с каждым ответом на мой аналог keep alive. Но, очевидно, мы здесь привязываемся к периодичности keep alive и могут вознивать нежелательные задержки отправки запросов от бэкенда.
2. Использовать для канала от бэкенда к фронтенду WebSocket. Но здесь мы уходим от HTTP-запросов, чего не хотелось бы делать. Возможно есть и другие сложности, которых я пока не вижу.
3. Использовать для канала от бэкенда к фронтенду fetch с длинным временем ожидания. На фронтенде отправлять через fetch HTTP-запрос и ждать ответа. Если истекает время ожидания, то отправлять новый запрос и так без конца. А на бэкенде не отправлять ответ, если нечего отправить, ну и отправлять ответ, если есть что послать от бэкенда к фронтенду. Но тут, как минимум, я вижу сложность в "граничных" моментах. Когда фронтенд уже считает, что не дождался ответа и готовится отправить новый запрос, а бэкенд отправляет ответ на старый запрос.

**ВОПРОС**: Подскажите, какой-то из моих вариантов имеет право на жизнь? Какие подводные камни в этих вариантах? Есть ли типовые варианты решения данной задачи и если есть, то какие?

Comment: вы никак не можете отправлять запросы с бэкенда на клиентский код. У вас два варианта - вебсокеты или отправлять запросы с клиента на бэк каждые N секунд или при необходимости. Если у вас данные для графика, то логичней сокеты использовать.

Comment: От бэкенда к фронтенду по инициативе бэкенда отправляются не данные для графиков, а "состояние" бэкенда. И это происходит очень редко.

Answer (score 0):

Если ваш фронтенд расчитан на десктопы, то использование [Web-socket](https://github.com/zaphoyd/websocketpp) - лучшее, что можно сделать (и на мой взгляд единственно верное решение).

Если фронт подразумевает мобильные платформы, то [Push-уведомления](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast-desktop-cpp-wrl) - лучшее, что можно сделать (и на мой взгляд единственно верное решение).